# Rendered image different from rendered image view

Tags: image, color, color-management

I'm rendering a scene in Blender, and for some reason, the rendered image section is different from the exported image. Note the difference in the wood colour appearance in the sun.

Rendered view
[image: Rendered image view]

Saved image
[image]

Colour settings

[image: Colour management]

Answer (score 0):

No answer as yet, so, here is my best *guess:*

In the top-right of the **3D Viewport**, make sure to select the correct shading option, then click the menu icon to get the viewport shading options:

[image: Viewport Shading options]

If you are not using the scene world or lights that could be an issue.

Next, in the **Outliner**, click the visibility filter dropdown.

[image: Outliner visibility filter]

That one between the eyeball (visible in 3D Viewport) and the camera (Renders) is the option to preview render in the viewport. Select it and check to make sure all your lights are enabled. (I don’t think it likely you have anything disabled here, but might as well check.)

Finally, you just need to look through your **Scene Properties** and **World Properties** to make sure everything is correct, alas.

I may be wrong on all counts, but these are the first things I’d check.

Comment: Everything is configured correctly, according to what you're suggesting. And, as of the sun, it's the Nishita sky texture. The problem could be due to weird colour space stuff...